# Pentaho data integration loop count variable

Tags: loops, variables, counter, pentaho, kettle

I want a simple loop function to count the number of loop like below in java programming:

```java
for (int i = 0; i <3; i++) {
    count = count+1;
}
System.out.println(count);
```

I am doing it using Pentaho data integration. so I have 1 job contain 3 transformations in it, where first transformation set the number of loop (above example 3), then second transformation click "Execute every input row" for looping, and set variable inside the transformation using Javascript with `getVariable()` and `setVariable()` function. the last transformation just get variable and write log to show the count.
The problem is every loop in the transformation 2 will get variable as 0. so it end up `result = 1`, what I expect is `3`.

added the project files here: [file](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1f8KTVZ4OseZkMqOl4sX2tlo4ebDyfGES?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

We'll need more details to help you, don't you have a simple sample of what you are trying to accomplish?
You can pass variables to a transformation from the job, so I don't think you'll need the getVariable() and setVariable() methods, you can just use the configuration properties of the transformation to execute:

[image: Passing a value to a variable in a job]

I prefer using parameters (next tab) better than arguments/variables, but that's my preference.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I added the project files link. my problem is not passing the variable, but is the variable value during looping.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, in t2 transformation, you are getting the variable and setting a new value for the same variable at the same time, which does not work in the same transformation. When you close the Set variable step you get this warning:

[image: Set variable step warning]

To avoid it you need to use two variables, one you set before executing the loop, and another set each time you execute the loop or after executing the loop with the last value.

I have modified your job to make it work, in t1 transformation, I have added a new field (rownum_seq) created with the Add sequence step, to know how much to add to variable cnt in each execution of the loop. I could have used your id field, but in case you don't have a similar field in your real world job, that's the step you need to achieve something similar. I have modified the variable name to make more clear what I'm doing, in t1 I set the value of variable **var_cnt_before**.

In t2 transformation, I read var_cnt_before, and set the value of **var_cnt_after** as the sum of var_cnt_before + rownum_seq, this means I'm changing the value of var_cnt_after each time t2 is executed.

In t3 transformation, I read var_cnt_after, which has the value of the last execution of t2.

You could also calculate var_cnt_after in t1 and not modify it in t2, using the Group by step to get the max value of rownum_seq, so you don't need to modify that variable each time you execute t2, depending on what you need to achieve you might need to use it or change in t2 or you just need the final value so you calculate it in t1.

This is the [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fSwEcIJpaMfC7dYto_O7xi8x9icUBy7e/view?usp=sharing) to the modified job and transformations.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  although I found it not exactly what I want. you answer is basically calculate the count outside the loop inside t1, which is the rownum_seq, and the final answer is based on the last loop. What if I just want to add the cnt based on some calculated result inside t2? like for example: for (int i = 0; i <3; i++) {
    if (my calculate result== true)  {count = count+1;}
}
System.out.println(count);

Comment: In that case you use a second variable to set the new result, but that second variable is going to change after each execution of the loop, if you need to have that value for each execution of the loop, you'll have to store it in a table or file (and don't use a variable, you'll use the column in that table/file). You also have the Repeat action in a job, I haven't used it before, check the samples in your PDI installation to see how to use it, but if you need to stop the loop when a calculation reachs a value, I think you can use it.

Comment: I can't find what is "Repeat action in a job" in pentaho data integration, can you elaborate more on this ? Thanks

Comment: Upps! Looking into Pentaho official documentation I see they are called Job entries, not Job actions, and the Repeat entry is not an official one, seems it got included with my flavor of Pentaho, probably something developed by Matt Casters (the initial mind behind Kettle, original name for Pentaho Data Integration before it became a tool in the Pentaho Suite), it's probably part of his kettle-needful-things plugin: https://github.com/mattcasters/kettle-needful-things.